# How to setup URL paths conveniently, making them different from absolute ones?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

This is my first question on Stack Overflow so far.

I provide so much information, because I have a feeling that I'd gone some wrong way from the beginning, so there may be a much better solution/approach using PHP only.

### Info

I've got a website located at my local XAMPP server and it is accessed using http://localhost/project/.

My project structure is the following:

```
|-- htdocs/
|---- project/
|------ css/
|------ img/
|------ js/
|------ less/
|------ files/
|------ src/
|-------- _config/
|---------- config.php
|-------- _template/
|---------- header.php
|---------- footer.php
|-------- pages/
|---------- portfolio/
|------------ showcase1.php
|------------ showcase2.php
|---------- company.php
|---------- contacts.php
|---------- portfolio.php
|------ .htaccess
|------ index.php
```

#### What I Need

The URLs should be the following:

1. http://localhost/project/ - root folder, index, home page
2. http://localhost/project/company - displays a webpage located at http://localhost/project/src/pages/company.php
3. http://localhost/project/portfolio/showcase1 - displays a webpage located at http://localhost/project/src/pages/portfolio/showcase1.php

#### What I've got

I've successfully achieved requirements №1 and №2 from my list "What I Need" above, however I can't get №3 work.

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /project/src/pages/$1.php [L,NC]
```

**PHP:**

Each **somepage.php** file contains:

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/project/src/_template/header.php");?>
```

**header.php**:

```
<?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/project/src/_config/config.php'); ?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
...
<base href="<?php echo SER_NAME; ?>">
...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <nav id="menu">
        <a href="company">Company</a>
        <a href="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="portfolio/showcase1">Schowcase1</a>
        <a href="portfolio/showcase2">Schowcase2</a>
        <a href="contacts">Contacts</a>
    </nav>
    ...
```

**config.php**:

```
<?php 
$basedir = '/project/';
define('DOC_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $basedir);
define('SER_NAME', "//" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $basedir);
define('TEMPLATE', DOC_ROOT . 'src/_template');
define('CSS_PATH', SER_NAME . 'css');
define('JS_PATH', SER_NAME . 'js');
define('IMG_PATH', SER_NAME . 'img'); 
define('FILE_PATH', SER_NAME . 'files');
?>
```

## Questions

1. How can I achieve №3 from my list "**What I need**" above? What .htaccess rule is required in my case?
2. If I'd gone the wrong way, which solution/approach may be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's going to be a bit of confusion with your rules because portfolio is both a folder and a php script. The first thing is maybe add a rewrite condition so that the rule doesn't get applied unless the php file actually exists (this won't solve #3)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/project/(\w+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/project/src/pages/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /project/src/pages/$1.php [L,NC]
```

The `-f` checks whether the file exists. This is something you probably want to do otherwise if someone types this into the browser's address bar:

```
http://localhost/project/blahblah
```

They'll get a 404 response saying "/project/src/pages/blahblah.php doesn't exist", which reveals the internal routing of your project.

Then, *before* this rule, you'll need something special to route into the portfolio folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/project/portfolio/(\w+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/project/src/pages/portfolio/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^portfolio/(\w+)$ /project/src/pages/portfolio/$1.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/project/(\w+)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/project/src/pages/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /project/src/pages/$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I really appreciate it.

Unfortunately, the provided .htaccess rules didn't help me somehow. I still get the 404.

What I've tried after changing .htaccess: restarted the apache server; cleared the browser data, cache, etc.; tried a different browser; changed the /portfolio/ folder to /portfolio1/ everywhere in order make it different from the portfolio.php page.

Unfortunately, none of these attempts helped.

Comment: **New observation**: rewriting `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/project/portfolio/(\w+)$` to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/project/(\w+)$` makes the page `localhost/project/src/pages/portfolio/showcase1.php` accessible at `http://localhost/project/showcase1`. In other words, the real issue is that specifying any project's subdirectory in the output URL to make the page accessible at `localhost/project/subdirectory-name/page-name` is not working.

Comment: @rade363 I forgot a "portfolio" in the rewrite rule's regex